# How to write not equal to query in Marklogic?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I have the following xml structure:-

```
<patent-assignors>
  <patent-assignor>
    <name>VOLPENHEIN, ROBERT A.</name>
    <execution-date>
      <date>19841204</date>
    </execution-date>
  </patent-assignor>
</patent-assignors>

<patent-assignees>
  <patent-assignee>
    <name>PROCTER &amp; GAMBLE COMPANY, THE</name>
    <address-2>A CORP. OF  OHIO</address-2>
    <city>CINCINNATI</city>
    <state>OHIO</state>
  </patent-assignee>
</patent-assignees>
```

I want to return those records where **patent-assignor** name is not equal to **patent-assignee** name. But I don't want to use where clause as it slows down the query. I want to filter the results in the search itself.  How can I do this ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to perform / expected output? What's your current code? Are these two XML files (the snippets you pasted do not form valid XML)?

Comment: Its not the full xml. I have posted here just a part of my full xml file. I want to perform search based on the Patent Assignor and Patent Assignee names and want those results where Patent Assignor and Patent-Assignee names are not the same.

Comment: Please add some valid XML (it must not be the full file of course) and what output you want to have. As you seem to have some code running using `where` clauses, you could post that to. This all helps us in understanding what you want to do exactly - at least I haven't got a clue. Valid XML to work with is crucial if you want your question answered.

Answer (score 2):

This works for the provided example. Haven't tested with multiple assignees, or explored performance.

```
/patent[patent-assignors/patent-assignor/name != patent-assignees/patent-assignee/name]
```

Based on

```
xdmp:document-insert('/patent.xml',
  <patent>
    <patent-assignors>
      <patent-assignor>
        <name>VOLPENHEIN, ROBERT A.</name>
        <execution-date>
          <date>19841204</date>
        </execution-date>
      </patent-assignor>
    </patent-assignors>
    <patent-assignees>
      <patent-assignee>
        <name>PROCTER &amp; GAMBLE COMPANY, THE</name>
        <address-2>A CORP. OF  OHIO</address-2>
        <city>CINCINNATI</city>
        <state>OHIO</state>
      </patent-assignee>
    </patent-assignees>
  </patent>
)
```

Comment: The above comment works for this scenario. For, multiple assignees try to loop using for to get result